# Android app crashes when opening Branch link

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, deep-linking, branch.io

The problem goes as follows:

1. Open app normally from app drawer
2. Press home button to send the app to the background
3. Open Branch link from WhatsApp or Facebook Messenger
4. App crashes (out of memory)

However, the following steps work just fine:

1. Open the app through Branch link
2. Press home button to send the app to the background
3. Open a different Branch link

Here is the what happens when the app crashes:

```
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495): Process: com.somecompany.Someapp, PID: 19495
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495): java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [main]
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495): Unity version     : 5.6.0f3
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495): Device model      : Sony D6633
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495): Device fingerprint: Sony/D6633/D6633:6.0.1/23.5.A.1.291/2769308465:user/release-keys
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 84934668 byte allocation with 16776896 free bytes and 61MB until OOM
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:467)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:497)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at com.unity3d.player.i.onLayoutChange(Unknown Source)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16731)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16722)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16722)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2685)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16722)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2175)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1935)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1111)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6017)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
05-19 15:56:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(19495):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
05-19 15:56:02.855: D/ActivityManager(935): New dropbox entry: com.somecompany.Someapp, data_app_crash, 30b67bc9-f4db-4507-b486-a6382778be7f
05-19 15:56:02.857: W/ActivityManager(935):   Force finishing activity com.somecompany.Someapp/io.branch.unity.BranchUnityActivity
```

And here is my manifest:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.somecompany.someapp" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <permission android:name="com.somecompany.someapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true" android:name="io.branch.referral.BranchApp">
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="fb1642292226066339" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID" android:value="\ 62138035114" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" android:value="\ 62138035114" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="8487000" />
    <meta-data android:name="wappier_debug" android:value="true" />
    <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.TestMode" android:value="false" />
    <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey.live" android:value="key_live_bnEyrJEa3GdHlq7FeCzr3annDxmJft9j" />
    <receiver android:name="com.kii.cloud.unity.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="com.somecompany.someapp" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.androidnative.features.notifications.LocalNotificationReceiver" />
    <receiver android:name="sdk.wappier.com.receivers.WappierReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.kii.cloud.unity.GcmIntentService" />
    <provider android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1642292226066339" android:exported="true" />
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="PACKAGE_NAME.MESSAGE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="io.branch.unity.BranchUnityActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape">
      <intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
          <data android:scheme="https" android:host="myapp.app.link" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="myapp-alternate.app.link" />
        </intent-filter>
        <data android:host="open" android:scheme="myapp" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="unity" />
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyOverlay" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyFullscreen" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyBrowser" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.VideoPlayer" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|touchscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.androidnative.AndroidNativeProxy" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity android:name="com.androidnative.features.social.common.SocialProxyActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="oauth" android:host="com.somecompany.someapp" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.androidnative.gms.core.GameClientBridge" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDeepLinkingActivity" android:exported="true" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDialogsActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.androidnative.gms.core.GooglePlaySupportActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityAppLinkActivity" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityGameRequestActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityCreateGameGroupActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityJoinGameGroupActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.AppInviteDialogActivity" />
  </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.somecompany.someapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
  <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />-->
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap memory management is a horror dating back to the early days of Android. I suggest using a library like Glide or Picasso to handle your bitmaps, and customizing the cache as needed. I don't know what you're using now but those are my go-tos. There's tons of information regarding bitmap oom issues on stackoverflow, it does not relate to Branch, unless of course you are passing tons of byte image data through link referring params in which case we do not support that. If you continue to struggle and find that it correlates to Branch's allocation of memory and not your bitmaps, please write in to integrations@branch.io and I'll take a look!